# How to bypass website's security certificate in IE using Ruby/Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate some IE browser tests using Ruby/Selenium WebDriver.

When I run the following code, it opens a new IE browser with the url but it always tells that 'There is a problem with this website's security certificate.'

Is there any way to set the IE profile/capabilities using Ruby similar to the ones used in Java?

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
driver.get "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
```

Comment: If it is the case, hope you can add the website certificate to trusted publishers list so that it doesn't prompt for certificate from next time. I was able to do it for firefox, but not sure of IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to set it by any capabilities, even if you were using Java. If you have found any approaches to achieve it in Java, please post it and see if it can be translated into Ruby.

But you can always simulate the clicking to bypass it.

```
# Tested under Windows 7, IE 10, Ruby 2.0.0
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
driver.get "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```